# Cloning ubuntu boot into software RAID 1 array

Tags: boot, partitioning, raid, mdadm

I have a Ubuntu server whose boot drive exists on an old HDD. I am wanting to clone this boot drive over to a RAID 1 SSD array. I don't know how to go about this correctly, since it will be a software RAID configuration.

I've created the RAID 1 array with mdadm and tried to clone into it with clonezilla. However, as I feared, the RAID array didn't show up to clonezilla (I assume since it was a software RAID configured in Ubuntu?).

How should I go about cloning my HDD onto a RAID array? I've never done anything with RAID before, so any help is very appreciated :)